# How to wait for a signal to be assigned new value within a process without using wait statement in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Basically I have to code a university project in vhdl. The main issues is that during a process I need assign a std_logic signal a '1' value so that a secondary process can start. I'm aware that the assignment to a signal is at the next clock cycle. But the problem is that I need to create a synthesizable hardware component so i can't really use wait statements. So here is the question: how can I wait a cycle of clock without using wait statements?

Comment: The signal will assume the new value at the next clock cycle if you make the assignment in a clocked process. You said you are aware of that, so I don't understand what exactly you're asking.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "_sensitivity list_". And no, it is not true that "_the assignment to a signal is at the next clock cycle_". The assignment to a signal is at the time **you** decide with your VHDL code. It can be one delta-cycle after the next rising edge of a clock. It can be sometime else. Up to you.

Comment: I suspect the search you want to do is, how do I code a flip-flop (sometimes also called register) in VHDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use clocked process with a structure as follows. Process_2 will start on the clock cycle after start_signal is set.

```
process_1 : process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    start_signal <= '1';
  end if;
end process;

process_2 : process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    if start_signal then
      --do stuff
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```